# Dynamic content in Magnific popup from button in infobox attached to Google Maps marker

Tags: google-maps, dynamic, infobox, magnific-popup

I need to load different content into a Magnific-popup which opens when clicking buttons inside infoboxes attached to markers in Google Maps.

I plan to list the content in an array outside the magnificPopup function (see below) that defines all the markers with corresponding content. How do I call the right content into the magnific-popup? Do I target the marker, the button or the infoBox? ...and how?

```
  window.google.maps.event.addListener(infoBox, "domready", function () {
  $('.open-popup').on('click', function () {
  $.magnificPopup.open({
    items: 
      {
        src: $('<div class="white-popup">Dynamically created element</div>'), // Dynamically created element
        type: 'inline'
      }
  });
  });
});
```

A working example of where I am at is here >>  http://jsfiddle.net/asier_adq/JdWmm/4/

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Where are you expecting the dynamic content to come from?

Comment: They will be sourced from other folders in same website. There will be up to 20 markers each one with and infobox. Forgot to say the infoboxes will contain different number of buttons, from only one to upto three.

Comment: But how are you going to pass that location information into the marker constructor or infowindow?

Comment: Are they not being picked from the markerData array by addMarkers() and attachBox() ?

Comment: I don't know, are they?  Where are you using them? Maybe you should clarify your question, what specifically are you trying to do in this example that isn't working?

Comment: At the moment every button in any infobox loads the same one content into the magnific-popup. I need each button to load different content unique to that button.

Comment: What have you done to do that?  Where does the unique content come from?  Is this the "always shows the content of the last one" issue?  Could you update your question to include more specifics about what is working and what isn't?

Comment: Sorry if I not making it clear. Currently the dummy content is defined inside $.magnificPopup.open ...  src: $('<div class="white-popup">Dynamically created element</div>'). But I would imagine it would be called there from an array of markers with their corresponding content. The question I have is I don't know how to match content called with specific buttons.

Comment: @geocodezip, I have edited the question to be more specific. I hope this is enough. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!  In this case Infoboxes are the key to linking a click to a marker.  So given that `var ib = new InfoBox();`

Then, inside a function that attaches infoboxes to the markers I add a new property 'num'  to the 'ib' object and define it by each markers 'i' variable. `ib.num = i;`

Then I can use it inside the magnificPopup function to call for the triggered marker's values I have stored in an array. `markerData[ib.num][7]`

The new script:

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(ib, "domready", function () {
  $('.open-popup-photo').on('click', function () {
      $.magnificPopup.open({
              items: {
              src: markerData[ib.num][7] 
             },
          type: 'image' // this is default type
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @asier_js, I am also encountering issues on setting up dynamic content inside infoboxes. Could you possibly help me?